# What is the WinE or Ubuntu version of doing this?

Tags: networking, wine

Add the following IP addresses to the "hosts" file on "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc": 
(Edit: I don't have the "hosts" file)

```
216.98.48.18 127.0.0.1 
216.98.48.53 127.0.0.1 
216.98.48.57 127.0.0.1 
216.98.48.133 127.0.0.1 
216.98.48.134 127.0.0.1
```

source (in case you want it) http://www.gog.com/forum/assassins_creed_directors_cut/ac_hangs/post7

Comment: @chili555 thanks for the edit, I should've noticed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open a terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Open the `hosts` file in an editor with the command below

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/hosts
   ```
3. Copy the given lines
4. Paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> into the editor
5. Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
6. Exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: @Syreth: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Where should Ubuntu's file be? I don't have it in my virtual C: 

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/hosts` in a terminal

Comment: Agh sorry I really don't know why I didn't see that 

Comment: @Fabby Okay I'll try it in a bit now

Comment: Success? Give me a ping.

Comment: Apparently it's just a simple text document, I don't know why it's in etc, though. This isn't English, where should I add the lines?

Comment: At the end of the file.

Comment: Okay, and why there? I mean how does this file work?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29